# Как подставить значение input-а в некоторые части div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть много прогресс-баров. Связанные прогресс-бары и input-ы имеют одинаковый класс и id. Как подставить значение input-а в div в те три места, где написано 50 (style width, aria-valuenow, сам текст в div)?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <input type="number" id="aaa" value="30" />
    <div class="progress mb-1">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-success aaa" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">50</div>
    </div>

    <input type="number" id="bbb" value="40" />
    <div class="progress mb-1">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-success bbb" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">50</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нет ничего сложного: ловить ивент ввода текста, искать элемент по классу, который равен содержимому из id, изменять свойства элемента.

```js
addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  let progressEl = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.id)[0];
  if (progressEl) {
    progressEl.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', e.target.value);
    progressEl.style.width = `${e.target.value}%`;
    progressEl.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="number" id="aaa" value="30" />
<div class="progress mb-1">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success aaa" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">50</div>
</div>

<input type="number" id="bbb" value="40" onchange="" />
<div class="progress mb-1">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success bbb" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">50</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Красивое решение )

Comment: А как его выполнять при загрузке? Через ```window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'``` не получается

Comment: @Юра Почему? По идее должно работать в виде коллбэка `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { код... });`

Comment: Да, странно, не хочет работать. Думал что конфликтует с bootstrap, jquery или jquery mobile, но нет, не помогло. При этом с ```addEventListener('input'``` прекрасно выполняется.

Comment: @Юра А как Вы пишете? Вам нужно в коллбэк слушателя ивента `DOMContentLoaded` поместить весь js-код, который дан в ответе (т.е будет слушатель в слушателе, первый исполняется только один раз, а тот, который для инпута, уже при каждом изменении). Вы же так делаете?

Comment: А, нет, просто заменял слушателя. Спасибо, завтра попробую. С Новым годом!

Comment: Не сработало. Только на input реагирует ```  addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
   addEventListener('input', (e) => {
     let progressEl = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.id)[0];
     if (progressEl) {
    progressEl.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', e.target.value);
    progressEl.style.width = 'calc(100% / ( 20000 / ${e.target.value} ) )';
    progressEl.innerHTML = e.target.value;
     }
   });
  });```

Comment: @Юра Так и должно на input реагировать и изменять. А что должно быть? И проверяйте формулу в `calc` – 100%/20000/100 условно - визуально это 0.

Comment: С calc я наведу порядок, для этого у меня мозгов хватает :)
Нужно при загрузке страницы просто брать готовое value из ```<input>``` и делать то что внутри ```if (progressEl) {}```