# Как сделать чтобы скрипт выполнялся при загрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript

Есть много `<input type="hidden">` и скрипт, который делает что-то очень важное ))
За скрипт спасибо [Vladimir Gonchar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1482630/191574). Но как сделать чтобы скрипт выполнялся при загрузке страницы, а не при изменении input-ов?

```js
        addEventListener('input', (e) => {
          let progressEl = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.id)[0];
          if (progressEl) {
            progressEl.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', e.target.value);
            progressEl.style.width = `${e.target.value}`;
            progressEl.innerHTML = e.target.value;
          }
        });
```

```html
<div class="progress mb-1" style="height:0.5rem">
    <input type="hidden" class="localstoragesave" id="hodba-2023-01-03" value="16603" />
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success hodba-2023-01-03" role="progressbar" style="width: 0; font-size: 0.5rem;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="20000" data-den="03.01.23 — ">0</div>
</div>

<div class="progress mb-1" style="height:0.5rem">
    <input type="hidden" class="localstoragesave" id="hodba-2023-01-02" value="10463" />
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success hodba-2023-01-02" role="progressbar" style="width: 0; font-size: 0.5rem;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="20000" data-den="02.01.23 — ">0</div>
</div>

<div class="progress mb-1" style="height:0.5rem">
    <input type="hidden" class="localstoragesave" id="hodba-2023-01-01" value="8589" />
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success hodba-2023-01-01" role="progressbar" style="width: 0; font-size: 0.5rem;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="20000" data-den="01.01.23 — ">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать событие **[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    let progressEl = document.getElementById(СЮДА_ВПИСАТЬ_ID);        
    
    if (progressEl) {
        let progressValue = progressEl.value;
        progressEl.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', progressValue);
        progressEl.style.width = progressValue;
        progressEl.innerHTML = progressValue;
    }
});
```

---

Данный код расположить после первого, который навешивает события `addEventListener('input'`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.progress input[type="hidden"]').forEach((el) => {
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles:true}));
    });
});
```

Comment: Вписать ID не получится, input-ов на странице очень много. Из за этого Vladimir Gonchar использовал ```document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.id)[0]```

Comment: @Юра окей, скажите, что такое по-вашему `e`, откуда оно появляется и что означает (что в нём содержится)? А ещё лучше  про `e.target`

Comment: Если бы я знал Алексей, если бы я знал... 

Comment: @Юра тогда почитайте информацию и приходите с ответом на заданный вопрос

Comment: @Юра добавил второй код, можно попробовать его как дополонение к тому, что в вопросе

Comment: Наверно будет проще с версткой. Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.progress input[type="hidden"]')`

Comment: Работает. Спасибо большое.